# Symfony2: ArticleManagerService

Tags: php, design-patterns, service, symfony

I want to create an ArticleManagerService which displays the base of my ArticleService.

This Service should hold CRUD-Methods for ArticleManagement and will get used from upper ArticleServices (like the ArticleFormService).

My question is now how I design this service.

I thought it would be a good way to create a class ArticleManagerService which provides methods that handle the entities.

Is this the right way?
Should I implement another abstract layer or should I leave this abstract layer away?

Best Regards,
Bodo

Answer (score 0):

The trick is it to create an abstract class and put the concrete classes (so the final ArticleManager) to the right persistence logic (ORM, ODM, ...)